# Question prototype and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototype

Excuse me I need a jQuery form plugin but in prototype and a tutorial about this.

or

I need a multipart plugin for ajax remote form in rails.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers. I used finally the iFrame hack